# Importing a JSON model into Three.js - Nothing showing

Tags: json, import, three.js

I'm using the following code and have been through the posts and definitely all the wiki and so forth.  No matter what .js JSON object I use, nothing appears in the browser window.  There are no flags in the browser console and I am prepared to run locally.  What is missing/done wrong?

```
<body>

    <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script>

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        var geometry;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});

        loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

        loader.load( "LeePerrySmith.js", function( geometry ) {

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
            mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
            mesh.position.y = 0;
            mesh.position.x = 0;
            mesh.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
            scene.add( mesh );
            mesh.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            alert("hit");

            } );


        camera.position.z = 5;

        var render = function () {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();

    </script>
</body>
```

---

### NEW CODE

```
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script>

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    var geometry;

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    loader.load( "LeePerrySmith.js", function( geometry ) {

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
        mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
        mesh.position.y = 0;
        mesh.position.x = 0;
        mesh.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
        scene.add( mesh );
        mesh.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        alert("hit");
        render();

        } );


    camera.position.z = 1000;

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var render = function () {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading is asynchronous. That is why you have a callback function. You are calling `render()` before the model loads.

1. Move `render()` to the last line of the callback function. Or do what most users do and add an animation loop.
2. Move you camera back to z = 1000. It may be inside the model.
3. You are not using your originial red material. Do this: `var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
4. `side` is a property of `material`, not `mesh`: set `mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`, if you feel you need that.

Comment: I've included your suggestions and still, nothing but the alert.  Modified Code posted.

Comment: You did not implement my first instruction.

Comment: Still nothing.  I've implemented all three correctly I believe, but without an animation loop (i really don't want to animate this one).

Comment: Your code works for me. Make sure the model is consistent with the current version of the library. Remember, it is your responsibility to get your code to work, not mine. After you figure it out, please remember to accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark. Point #1 will be very helpful to others.

Comment: @gustable get rid of the mesh and material outside the loader. Then in the loader where you have `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` give it a color `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00})`. Your code is mostly fine now, its just a white model on a white background me thinks :)

Comment: OMG!!  @Darryl, thank you for seeing the obvious.  I have been at this for months.